# Obtain the analytics region from mesh or vtk file

Tags: data, mesh

Is it possible to obtain the region inequalities from a mesh file (vtk-file).

On gmsh I build a Sphere, and with Mathematica  I would like to obtain the analytics region function, that's is possible?.

I can obtain the vertex from the file sphere.vtk, using that:

```
data = Import["mesh_2_5.vtk", "VertexData"];
```

But I do not know if exists a routine for obtaining the analytics equations that define this structure. The sphere.vtk can be downloaded from: https://gofile.io/d/OscWUA

thanks

Comment: Your Sphere.vtk file doesn't contain any inequalities or expressions. They are all points and cells. If you want the equation for this sphere, you need to perform a fit to find parameters of a sphere equation.

Comment: You do `sphere = Import["Sphere.vtk"]; mesh = DiscretizeGraphics@sphere; coords = MeshCoordinates[mesh];` Then have a look at `ListPointPlot3D[coords, BoxRatios -> 1]` You only need the radius since it's clearly centered at zero. The radius is `Max[Norm /@ coords]` which returns 1. So your sphere is best fit by `Sphere[{0,0,0},1]` - or better `Ball[{0,0,0},1]` since points can appear on the inside.

Comment: Thank you very much, do you know if there is any function in Mathematica that looks for the equation of the surface of the sphere ?, from the numerical data

Comment: No - just get the points on the shell with `pts=MeshCoordinates[ConvexHullMesh[coords]]` then assuming a uniform distribution of points, `c=Mean[pts]` will get the center, and `Max[Norm[#-c]&/@pts]` will get you the radius.

Comment: In fact I just realized, you could do this whole thing with `BoundingRegion[DiscretizeGraphics@sphere, "MinBall"]`

Comment: thanks, do you know if can do that for irregular shapes?

Comment: You mean fit a sphere around an irregular shape? Yes it will try to find a minimum volume ball around the shape - see the documentation for other things like min ellipsoids and cuboids. However if you're trying to fit an arbitrary shape onto some points, that's a very different question and it's quite a difficult problem.

Comment: thanks,no, I mean, to determine a system of inequalities that define the internal region

Comment: Get the faces with `MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2]` and calculate their normals and a random point on the surface. This should be enough to set up a system of inequalities provided the normals point out of the object. But your sphere is problematic because you have self intersecting geometry and faces internal to the sphere. If your objects are convex, you could treat this with a `ConvexHullMesh` first.

Comment: `data = Import["mesh_2_5.vtk", "VertexData"]` does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The question specified that the shape was a sphere, "On gmsh I build a Sphere, ...." At most there may have been *interior* points or cells. One could then use ConvexHull to find surface points.

With four noncoplanar points on a shape known to be a ball or sphere, it is possible to compute the equation:

```mma
points = (#1 + {1, 2, 3} & ) /@ 
    PolyhedronData["Tetrahedron", "VertexCoordinates"]
    
expr = Plus @@ ((Indexed[x, #1] - Indexed[a, #1])^2 & ) /@ 
      Range[3] - Indexed[a, 4]^2 == 0
      
values = (Indexed[a, #1] & ) /@ Range[4]

expr /. Solve[Indexed[a, 4] >= 0 && 
    And @@ Table[expr /. (Indexed[x, #1] -> p[[#1]] & ) /@ 
        Range[3], {p, points}], values]
```

1. $\left(
   \begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & 2 & \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{6}}+3 \\
    1-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}} & \frac{3}{2} & 3-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{6}} \\
    1-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}} & \frac{5}{2} & 3-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{6}} \\
    1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 2 & 3-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{6}} \\
   \end{array}
   \right)$
2. $(x_1-a_1){}^2+(x_2-a_2){}^2+(x_3-a_3){}^2-a_4{}^2=0$
3. $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$
4. $(x_1-1){}^2+(x_2-2){}^2+(x_3-3){}^2-\frac{3}{8}=0$

I was unable to download your data file. Therefore, I faked up some data. Otherwise, points would have been some 4 noncoplanar points from your data set.

The method generalizes to $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}\enspace}$
with one more point than the dimensionality of the space.
For $\mathbb{R}^0$, the space is only a point with no coordinates. It is both the input and the output. For $\mathbb{R}^1$, the input is the two points on the number line and the output is the point at the coorindate of the mean of each of the input point coordinates and a radius of the distance (remember, distance is always nonnegative) to either of the edge (circumference) points. Then it gets interesting.

Of course, I may have missed something.